What is the correct way to pass values between Composables when implementing a Shared Transition?
I need to pass a value or ID from MainContent to Details. What is the best way to achieve this between Composables? I have written some code, but I’m looking for a better approach.
   SharedTransitionLayout {
var showDetails by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedValue by remember { mutableStateOf("") } // Shared value

AnimatedContent(
    showDetails,
    label = "basic_transition"
) { targetState ->
    if (!targetState) {
        MainContent(
            onShowDetails = { value ->
                selectedValue = value // Set the value in MainContent
                showDetails = true
            },
            animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
            sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout
        )
    } else {
        DetailsContent(
            onBack = {
                showDetails = false
            },
            value = selectedValue, // Pass the value to DetailsContent
            animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
            sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout
        )
    }
}

}

You can implement shared element transitions either with AnimatedContent, or NavHost, also AnimatedVisibility but not for this case though.
SharedTransitionLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "home",
    ) {
        composable("home") {
            MainContent(
                onShowDetails = { value ->
                    navController.navigate("details/$value")
                },
                animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
                sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout
            )
        }

        composable(
            "details/{id}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("id") { type = NavType.IntType })
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            val selectedValue = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("id") ?: 0
            DetailsContent(
                onBack = {
                    navController.navigateUp()
                },
                value = selectedValue, // Pass the value to DetailsContent
                animatedVisibilityScope = this@AnimatedContent,
                sharedTransitionScope = this@SharedTransitionLayout
            )
        }
    }
}

When you use NavHost back press navigates from DetailsContent to MainContent. With AnimatedContent you need to override back press to be able to stay in same screen even if pressing a button sets showDetails = false back button will navigate to previous screen.
I posted examples with either of them here.
